# Factorize the multivariate polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factorization

I came across the following problem:

Factorize the multivariate polynomial given by:

$$w*(A^2-2l*A+1)*f+v*(B^2-2m*B+1)g+u*(C^2-2n*C+1)*h+(w*(x+2A*l+A*s-l*s-A^2-1)+v*(y+2B*m+B*t-m*t-B^2-1)+u*(z+2C*n+C*q-n*q-C^2-1))$$

over the integers. Here all the arguments are positive integers variables.

Comment: `IrreduciblePolynomialQ[
 f + x - 1 + 2 A*a + A*y - a*y + A^2*f - A^2 - 2 A*a*f]` answers `True`.

Comment: The `IrreduciblePolynomialQ` command is easily found in the documentation, e.g. [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PolynomialFactoring.html).

Comment: @user64494: Sorry, I have entered the wrong polynomail. See the edited question.

Comment: Still irreducible.

Answer (score 1):

```
IrreduciblePolynomialQ[w∗ (A^2 - 2 ∗l∗A + 1) ∗f + v∗ (B^2 - 2 ∗m∗B + 1) g + 
u∗ (C^2 - 2 ∗n∗C + 1) ∗h + (w∗ (x + 2 ∗A∗l + A∗s - l∗s - A^2 - 1) + 
v∗ (y + 2 ∗B∗m + B∗t - m∗t - B^2 - 1) + 
u∗ (z + 2 ∗C∗n + C∗q - n∗q - C^2 - 1))]
```

> `True`

The `IrreduciblePolynomialQ` command is easily found in the documentation, e.g. [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PolynomialFactoring.html).